# Unable to install Kivy in Virtual Environment Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, kivy, conda, anaconda3, conda-forge

First of all I love Anaconda.
I have some issues with Virtual Environments.
I will give all information so i hope somebody can help me!

**Operation System: Windows 11
Conda BASE Python Version: 3.10.13**
I had installed Anaconda in the past so i did **NOT** use below commands to update it.

```
X conda update conda (Not used)
X Zconda update anaconda (Not used)
```

I used conda install **anaconda=2023.09** to update it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**PROMLEM:**

First of all i install Jupyter (conda install -c anaconda jupyter) with out a problem!
But after that, if i try to install Kivy (conda install -c conda-forge kivy) I get some errors!

[image]

How can i fix this problem? Each time when i want to install different libraries to one ENV, it always stuck in loading and give some this kind errors.

```
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/win-64::openssl-3.0.11-h2bbff1b_2
  - defaults/win-64::openssl-3.0.11-h2bbff1bdone
```

Too Strange That
If i create two different Environments so i can install Jupyter to one of them and i can install Kivy to other one without a problem!

I tried to create 3.9 Python Env but nothing changed! Same errors!

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Kivy library packages conflict with Jupyter library.
So I created two virtual environments.
I just installed Jupyter on one of them.
And I installed Scrapy and Kivy to the other virtual environment.
The problem was fixed.

Thanks.